# Conditional Probability a Raffle

Tags: probability

I would like to know the probability of each number coming out in a raffle in which we have from $1$ to $25$ and are drawn $15$ numbers, would be $\frac{1}{15}$ or $\frac{1}{25}$, or another percentage?

Similar problem:

What is the probability of getting two five consecutive with a six-sided die? The probability of each independent event is equal to $\frac{1}{6}$. This gives us $\frac{1}{6}\times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$, $0.027$ or $2.7$%.

Answer (score 1):

If $15$ numbers are drawn out of $25$, the probability of any particular number coming up is $15/25=3/5$ (assuming they are drawn without replacement, i.e. $15$ different numbers are drawn).

For your second question, your answer is correct.